# Correct implementation of lapply

Tags: r, lapply

In so far as I understand it, when using r it can be more elegant to use functions such as lapply rather than for loops (that are used more often than not in other object oriented languages). However I cannot get my head around the syntax and am making foolish errors when trying to implement simple tasks with the command. For example:

I have a series of dataframes loaded from csv files using a for loop.The following dummy dataframes adequately describe the data:

```
x <- c(0,10,11,12,13)
y <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
z <- c(2,20,21,22,23)    
a <- c(0,6,5,4,3)
b <- c(1,7,8,9,10)
c <- c(2,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
df2 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I first generate a list of dataframe names (data_names- I do this when loading the csv files) and then simply want to sum the columns. My attempt of course does not work:

```
lapply(data_names, function(df) {
counts <- colSums(!is.na(data_names))
})
```

I could of course use lists (and I realise in the long run this maybe better) however from a pedagogical point of view I would like to understand lapply better.

Many thanks for any pointers

Comment: You wan to use `df` in your function rather than `data_names`...

Comment: +1 for reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really just your use of `is.na` and the fact you don't need to use the asignment operator `<-` inside the function. `lapply` returns a list which is the result of applying `FUN` to each element of the input list. You assign the output of `lapply` to a variable, e.g. `res <- lapply( .... , FUN )`.

I'm also not too sure how you made the list initially, but the below should suffice. You also don't need an anonymous function in this case, you can use the named `colSums` and also provide the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to take care of persky `NA`s in your data:

```
lapply( list( df1, df2 ) , colSums , na.rm = TRUE )
[[1]]
 x  y  z 
46  1 88 

[[2]]
 a  b  c 
18 35  2
```

So you can read this as:

- For each df in the list:
- apply `colSums` with the argument `na.rm = TRUE`

The result is a list, each element of which is the result of applying `colSums` to each df in the list.

Comment: Ah excellent, its nice to see that typing can be reduced even further. Thanks for your quick and eloquent response.

Comment: As an addendum I realise I can also use my original version in this form: `lapply(list( df1, df2 ), function(x) {colSums(!is.na(x))})` so that I can count the number of values in the columns.

Comment: @user1912925 sure, yes - I didn't realise that is what you wanted to do, but sure that'll work.